# How to access the value from the subscriber callback

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i want to use the variable value from subscriber callback function on other function.

```
 #! /usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan


class path_planning:
    def __init__(self): 
        print("initalizing publisher and subscriber")
        rospy.init_node("path_plan", anonymous=True)
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber(
            "/ebot/laser/scan", LaserScan, self.callback)
        rospy.spin()
        rospy.sleep(10)

def use(self):
    self.gg = 2
    return self.gg

def callback(self,msg):
    print("getting into callback")
    self.part_1 = msg.ranges[:145]
    self.part_2 = msg.ranges[145:289]
    self.part_3 = msg.ranges[289:433]
    self.part_4 = msg.ranges[433:577]
        self.part_5 = msg.ranges[577:]
        # print(self.part_1)
        
        # print(self.part_1)
        # values = splitter(self.part_1)
   


if __name__ =="__main__":
    path = path_planning()
    print(path.use())
```

i tried various ways still couldn't find one that works for me and also saw similar question on various forum. i dont know what am i doing wrong. can someone help me with that.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/390671/how-to-access-the-value-from-the-subscriber-callback/) by [Azeem](https://answers.ros.org/users/76171/azeem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello @Azeem,

I think your code indentation is wrong. You need to Just put a tab in your `use` and a `callback` function.

Your code should be in this form:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import rospy
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan


class path_planning:
    def __init__(self): 
        print("initalizing publisher and subscriber")
        rospy.init_node("path_plan", anonymous=True)
        self.sub = rospy.Subscriber(
            "/ebot/laser/scan", LaserScan, self.callback)
        rospy.spin()
        rospy.sleep(10)

    def use(self):
        self.gg = 2
        return self.gg

    def callback(self,msg):
        print("getting into callback")
        self.part_1 = msg.ranges[:145]
        self.part_2 = msg.ranges[145:289]
        self.part_3 = msg.ranges[289:433]
        self.part_4 = msg.ranges[433:577]
        self.part_5 = msg.ranges[577:]
            # print(self.part_1)

            # print(self.part_1)
            # values = splitter(self.part_1)



if __name__ =="__main__":
    path = path_planning()
    print(path.use())
```

I think now you will be able to access your `callback` and `use` functions.

> i want to use the variable value from subscriber callback function on other function.

And if you want to access the value of callback() and want to use it into use() function you need to declare it as `self.variable_name`  at the time of initializing the class.

---

Originally posted by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) with karma: 1622 on 2021-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2021-11-11**:
The following parts should have the same indentation as `self.part_4 = msg.ranges[433:577]`.

```
    self.part_5 = msg.ranges[577:]
    # print(self.part_1)

    # print(self.part_1)
    # values = splitter(self.part_1)
```

**Comment by [Ranjit Kathiriya](https://answers.ros.org/users/63046/ranjit-kathiriya/) on 2021-11-12**:
I am sorry! I will edit my answer. Thanks for pointing my mistake @miura.